# Asp.Net Core API CORS policy error only in file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I have CORS Policy blocking error only while uploading file to server using AspNet Core API 3.1. Adding cors policy to startup in different ways and using custom middleware not solved my problem.

Startup:

// ConfigureServices

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("EnableSVCCors", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .Build();
        });
    });
```

// Configure

```
    app.UseCors("EnableSVCCors");
```

All API methods working fine by calling from react client web site but while trying to upload image I have following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://172.16.1.34:1980/api/accounts/uploadAvatar' from origin
>   'http://172.16.1.35:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I also try to change cors policy as below but not working:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("EnableSVCCors", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins("http://172.16.1.35:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .Build();
        });
    });
```

Note: Calling http://172.16.1.34:1980/api/accounts/uploadAvatar using PostMan and sending base64 string as image is working fine! So there is no problem with access limits on folder where image going to be saved.

I also tried to add custom middleware as below but not working as yet:

```
    public class CorsMiddleWare
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CorsMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://172.16.1.35:3000");

        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}

public static class CorsMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleWare>();
    }
}
```

Any one have any idea please?

**EDIT :** Return headers in console is as below

> Request URL: http://172.16.1.34:1980/api/accounts/uploadAvatar
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020
>   03:50:49 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>   Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhb.....
>   Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 22869 Content-Type:
>   application/json;charset=UTF-8 Host: 172.16.1.34:1980 Origin:
>   http://172.16.1.35:3000 Referer:
>   http://172.16.1.35:3000/create-profile User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 {fileName: "avatar", mediaType:
>   "image/png",…} fileName: "avatar" mediaType: "image/png" buffer:
>   "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAgAE

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker It returned ( failed net::err_failed ). I updated my question with return headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved by changing the type of object is sending as image file to HttpFile contains in MultipartDataMediaFormatter.V2 https://github.com/iLexDev/ASP.NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter

**Upload View Model :**

```
public class ProfileAvatarUploadViewModel
{
    public HttpFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

**Api Controller :**

```
[HttpPost("UploadAvatar")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Roles = "Manager,Admin,User")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAvatar([FromBody] ProfileAvatarUploadViewModel model)
{
    var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

    if (userId == null || !await _userAccountRepository.IsExists(int.Parse(userId)))
    {
        return Forbid();
    }

    var avatarToUpload = new ProfileAvatarUploadModel
    {
        UserAccountId = int.Parse(userId),
        UploadedImage = model.Image
    };

    var uploadedAvatar = await _profileAvatarRepository.UploadAvatar(avatarToUpload);

    return Ok(uploadedAvatar);
}
```

**Repository :**

```
public async Task<ProfileAvatarViewModel> UploadAvatar(ProfileAvatarUploadModel model)
{
    var (key, value) = SVCardTools.SaveImage(model.UploadedImage);

    if (key.Equals(false))
    {
        throw new Exception(value);
    }

    var newAvatar = new ProfileAvatar
    {
        UserAccountId = model.UserAccountId,
        AvatarUrl = value,
        IsActive = false,
        IsPublic = false
    };

    _context.Entry(newAvatar).State = EntityState.Added;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return ProfileAvatarViewModel.Set(newAvatar);
}
```

**SaveImage function :**

```
    public static KeyValuePair<bool, string> SaveImage(HttpFile file)
    {
        var bytes = file.Buffer;

        try
        {
            var fileExt = file.MediaType.Split('/')[1];
            switch (fileExt.ToLower())
            {
                case "png":
                    fileExt = ".png";
                    break;
                case "jpg":
                    fileExt = ".jpg";
                    break;
                default:
                    return new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(false, "Message");
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            var saveFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\avatars",
                $"{sb}{fileExt}");

            var saveDbPath = $"{sb}{fileExt}";

            if (bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(true, saveDbPath);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var message = e.Message;
            return new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(false, message);
        }
    }
```